# undefined reference to determine_price;calc;print_result

Tags: c

i having some problem with C. could u pls help me. im very new in C.

i got this error:

D:\yana\mini.o:mini.c|| undefined reference to `determine_price'|

D:\yana\mini.o:mini.c|| undefined reference to `calc'|

D:\yana\mini.o:mini.c|| undefined reference to `print_result'|

||=== Build finished: 3 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 7 seconds) ===|

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>
    #include <math.h>


    void menu();
    float determine_price(int);
    float calc(float,int);
    void print_result(float);

    int main()
    {
        char selection;
        int qty,quantity;
        float price,pay,item_price,payment;
        char set;

        printf("**************************\n");
        printf("|AZRI & YANA'S CAKE HOUSE|\n");
        printf("**************************\n");
        printf("\n");
        printf("***************************\n");
        printf("|1 CUP-------------RM3.50 |\n");
        printf("|SET A(3 CUPS)-----RM10.00|\n");
        printf("|SET B(6 CUPS)-----RM20.00|\n");
        printf("|SET C(12 CUPS)----RM38.00|\n");
        printf("***************************\n");
        printf("\n");


        printf("enter Set and quantity:\n");
        scanf("%c %d",&selection,&qty);

        price=determine_price(set);
        pay= calc(price,qty);
        print_result(pay);

    return 0;
    }
    void menu()
    {
        printf("1 cup = RM3.50\n");
        printf("Set A = RM10.00\n");
        printf("Set B = RM20.00\n");
        printf("Set C = RM38.00\n");
    }
    float determine_price(int item_code)
    {
        float set;

           if(selection=='1')
            printf("1 cup = RM3.50\n");
        else if(selection=='A')
            printf("Set A = RM10.00\n");
        else if(selection=='B')
            printf("Set B = RM20.00\n");
        else if(selection=='C')
            printf("Set C = RM38.00\n");
        else
            printf("set not available\n");

        return(set);
    }
    float calc(float item_pricing,int quantity)
    {
        float answer;
        answer = item_price*quantity;
        return(answer);
    }
    void print_result(float payment)
    {
        printf("total cost = %4.2f",payment);
    }
```

wht do i hv to do to call function? do i need to call function() or is there mistake in my syntax?

> Edit:

after revised with help of you all, i make a little editing..

now, i got new error...

> D:\yana\mini.c||In function 'determine_price':|
>
> D:\yana\mini.c|54|error: 'selection' undeclared (first use in this function)|
>
> D:\yana\mini.c|54|note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in|
>
> D:\yana\mini.c||In function 'calc':|
>
> D:\yana\mini.c|70|error: 'item_price' undeclared (first use in this function)|
>
> ||=== Build finished: 2 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds) ===|

Edit Number 2;

> Edit Number 2;

i have found several mistake thank to all who answer my question.. here now, my new code... i try to make it clrscreen, however, it wont work... caN Someone help me?

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    void menu();
    int repeat();
    float determine_price(char);
    float calc(float,int);
    void print_result(float);

    int main()
    {
        char selection;
        int qty,quantity,choice;
        float price,pay,item_price,payment;
        //char set;

        while(choice!='2'){
            menu();
            printf("enter Set and quantity:\n");
            scanf("%c %d",&selection,&qty);

            price=determine_price(selection);
            pay= calc(price,qty);
            print_result(pay);
            choice = repeat();
        }

    return 0;
    }

    void menu()
    {
        printf("**************************\n");
        printf("|AZRI & YANA'S CAKE HOUSE|\n");
        printf("**************************\n");
        printf("\n");
        printf("***************************\n");
        printf("|1 CUP-------------RM3.50 |\n");
        printf("|SET A(3 CUPS)-----RM10.00|\n");
        printf("|SET B(6 CUPS)-----RM20.00|\n");
        printf("|SET C(12 CUPS)----RM38.00|\n");
        printf("***************************\n");
        printf("\n");
    }
    void clr(){
        system("cls");
    }
    int repeat(){
        int choice;
        printf("\n\n\n\n");
        printf("Press\n[1] to return to menu\n[2] to end system\n");
        scanf("%d",&choice);

        if(choice=='1'){
            clr();
        }
        return choice;
    }
    float determine_price(char selection){
        float setprice;

        if(selection=='1'){
            printf("1 cup = RM3.50\n");
            setprice=3.50;
        }
        else if(selection=='A'){
            printf("Set A = RM10.00\n");
            setprice=10.00;
        }
        else if(selection=='B'){
            printf("Set B = RM20.00\n");
            setprice=20.00;
        }
        else if(selection=='C'){
            printf("Set C = RM38.00\n");
            setprice=38.00;
        }
        else
            printf("set not available\n");

        return(setprice);
    }
    float calc(float item_pricing,int quantity){
        float answer;
        answer = item_pricing*quantity;
        return(answer);
    }
    void print_result(float payment){
        printf("total cost = RM%4.2f",payment);
    }
```

Comment: You put all sub-function into main?

Comment: And in a constructive way -- remove the last closing bracket and put it right after return 0; at the main() method's end.

Comment: ty for helping.. i did tht.. and i got some new error

Comment: new errors are about variables that are declared in a different function. You should pass them as parameters.

Comment: Those are very simple error, that message tell you everything you need to know. Just define variables if you are going to use them.

Comment: you mean, pass selection from main to out function?

Comment: oh, i hve to redeclare char selection inside function, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is correct, but you miss an } to close your main function.

You have to declare the specification of your functions out of main function.

es:

```
/* Forward declarations */
void a();
float b();

/* Main */ 
int main() {
  ...
}

/* Function's specifications */
void a() {
  ...
}

float b() {
   ...
}
```